# Symplectic form on $S^2$

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

$ω_p(u,v):= \langle p, u × v\rangle$ defines symplectic form on $S^2\subset \mathbf{R}^3$ for all $u,v\in T_p S^2$.

How to show that it is in fact volume form on $S^2$?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $J$ denotes the complex structure $Ju = p \times u$ induced by the cross product, $u$ is a unit tangent vector at $p$, and $v = Ju$, then $u \times v = p$, so $\omega_{p}(u, v) = \langle p, p\rangle = 1$.